# Additional custom place order button in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

For my checkout page I would like to have more than 1 "place order" button. Is there a script that generates this button? I haven't been able to find it so far.

I only found one where you can change the text of the button. But I need one where I can just generate a new one within the checkout page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place order button is located in WooCommerce `checkout/payment.php` template file *(line **`51`**)*:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>' ); ?>
```

Where `$order_button_text = __("Place order", "woocommerce");`

> Now as this button is located **inside** the checkout `<form>` and if you duplicate it **and you want it to work**, it requires to be **inside the checkout `<form>`**.

So you can include it in [any checkout template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/3.7.0/templates/checkout) or using available hooks like for example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'second_place_order_button', 5 );
function second_place_order_button() {
    $order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( "Place order", "woocommerce" ) );
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

The hook that you will use need to be located  **inside** the checkout `<form>`.

Comment: Hi, how do i exactly implement this in my checkout page. Is it with the do_action hook? So the above code goes in my function.php and then i'd have to call it in my checkout page?

Comment: @Kevin.a **There is 2 ways:** 1) [overriding WoooCommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) official documentation…so adding the 2nd button in a WooCommerce template… or … 2) Using available hooks (depending on where you want to display this additional button, as you don't mention the desired location): See [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide for Checkout Page](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/) to get some help and understand.

Comment: @Kevin.a When you use a snippet code as a hooked function that you add to your active theme's functions.php file (and saving), you have nothing else to do… The hook will make the job triggering the hooked function in the hook location (for an action hook, like in my code example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this hook?

```
add_action( '(specify the hook you wish to place it)', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

for example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

I did not tested it, need to check if it does not produce errors because of multiple buttons on the single product page.

Comment: this is an add to cart button. I am looking for one that submits the form. Is it possible to add an extra one?